# Turn floating point number into a valid Alpha value for an RGBA CSS colour

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am attempting to fill a Canvas element with a single linear gradient between White and a Dynamic colour that will be determined at runtime.

To this effect, I have this function, that receives a floating point number as it's argument, and I am attempting to plug that variable into the alpha value of a RGBA colour.

```
function setCanvas(fraction) {

    fraction = fraction.toFixed(2);
    context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var grad = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    grad.addColorStop(0, '#FFFFFF');
    grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, fraction)'); // SYNTAX ERROR
    context.fillStyle = grad;
    context.fill();

  }
```

This is the error message in the log:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'addColorStop' on 'CanvasGradient': The value provided ('rgba(255, 255, 255, fraction)') could not be parsed as a color.*

I can log the value of *fraction* and it is always normalized between 0.0 and 1.0, which is what the [documentation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color-4/#typedef-rgb-component) says it needs... but if I statically type in the same value (0.76, for example) into my RGBA colour, then everything works swimmingly...

Am I missing something obvious? Why isn't this working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do this

```
grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + fraction+ ')');
```

You're including the string fraction instead of the value.

Comment: BOOM. Thanks, that was it... I don't play with JS too much, and am still unused to dynamic variable types, so this string stuff always catches me... will accept the answer as soon as I can...